# Reasons to use CoreData rather than just fetching the data with a get request and saving it in a local variable

Tags: ios, json, core-data

I'm working on a new iOS app and I keep reading things online such as, "All apps that use backends should use CoreData".  I haven't been able to find to many reasons backing up this logic.  Are there any reasons that I am not realizing for why I should use CoreData in an application if the content is constantly changing and I don't need to sort or access the data offline?  I have gotten CoreData to work, I just don't fully see the benefit be is ease or performance.  Would anyone mind shedding some light on this topic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use it.

Some reasons you might use it in the case you've described:

- If you have a lot of data, too much to keep in memory on the device
- If you want undo–redo support
- You want support for fancy querying

Comment: Adding one more point, if there are entities with relationship. It would be much easier to keep data modularised using core data.